# How to set the level above which to display factor loadings from factanal() in R?

Tags: r, analysis, r-factor

I was performing factor analysis with data state.x77, which is in R by default. After running the analysis, I inspected the factor loadings.

```
> output = factanal(state.x77, factors=3, rotation="promax")
> ld = output$loadings
> ld

Loadings:
           Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
Population  0.161   0.239  -0.316 
Income     -0.149   0.681         
Illiteracy  0.446  -0.284  -0.393 
Life Exp   -0.924   0.172  -0.221 
Murder      0.917   0.103  -0.129 
HS Grad    -0.414   0.731         
Frost       0.107           1.046 
Area        0.387   0.585   0.101 

               Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
SS loadings      2.274   1.519   1.424
Proportion Var   0.284   0.190   0.178
Cumulative Var   0.284   0.474   0.652
```

It looks like that by default R is blocking all values less than 0.1. I was wondering if there is a way to set this blocking level by hand, say 0.3 instead of 0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
print(output$loadings, cutoff = 0.3)
```

see `?print.loadings` for the details.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thanks!